# Passing an argument to redux dispatch function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, event-handling

I want to build some buttons (from react-bootstrap Buttons) that know when the mouse cursor has entered and left them. No problem with hooking this up, and I get everything to fire just fine. However, if I have several such buttons, and each gets a name passed down to it, how do I get the name into the reducer?

In the following example, I want `bsName` to be passed to the reducer, take a peek at `mapsDispatchToProps`:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const InteractiveButton = ({
  bsStyle,
  bsName,
  bsText,
  dispButtonEnter,
  dispButtonLeave
}) => (
  <div>
    <Button
      onMouseEnter={dispButtonEnter}
      onMouseLeave={dispButtonLeave}
      bsStyle={bsStyle}
      bsSize="large"
      title={bsName}
      block
    >
      {bsText}
    </Button>
  </div>
);

InteractiveButton.propTypes = {
  bsStyle: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  bsName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  bsText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  dispButtonEnter: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  dispButtonLeave: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const dispButtonEnter = { type: 'BUTTON_MOUSE_ENTER' };
const dispButtonLeave = { type: 'BUTTON_MOUSE_LEAVE' };

function mapStateToProps() {
  return {};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispButtonEnter: e => dispatch({
      ...dispButtonEnter,
      buttonName: bsName <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< something like this, but functioning
      buttonEnterTarget: e.relatedTarget
    }),
    dispButtonLeave: e => dispatch({
      ...dispButtonLeave,
      buttonName: bsName <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< something like this, but functioning
      buttonLeaveTarget: e.relatedTarget
    })
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InteractiveButton);
```

Comment: What’s in your reducer?

Comment: as @jpdelatorre asked, this could be solved with adding the key to your reducer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should utilize **closures** properly here don't just dispatch directly instead make the call to the closure method that will receive the the name of button and then add that name in the payload.

```
closureFunction(btnName){
   dispatch({
      ...dispButtonEnter,
      payload:{name: btnName}
   })
}
```

In reducer you will be able to access the payload in action argument.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to use this (still new to JS and React). I get that this is a closure, but how to you pass it in to `mapDispToProps`? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Also I managed to get the button name by accessing the second argument of `mapDispToProps(dispatch, ownProps)`. is there a reason I shouldn't do it this way?

Comment: There is no issue in using ownProps but I'm not sure about weather you will get the title this way if you use <input>or <button> but it will work for the <Button>,  mapDispToProps is just providing you the functions as props and you can pass data as arguments to that function normally.

Comment: `//Mapping the dispatch to props
const mapDispatchToAppProps = dispatch => ({
 requestData: () => dispatch(fetchData()),
 setData:(data) => {console.log(data);dispatch({type:FETCH_DATA, payload:data});}
})

//Method to call
setDatatest = () => {
  var data =[{"id":0,"firstName":"Albertha","lastName":"Koelpin","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/vimarethomas/128.jpg","emailAddress":"Albertha36@cmegroup.com"}}]
  this.props.setData(data); 
 }
`